# Why is the Stock Market Cap / GDP ratio on FRED well out of date?

Tags: gdp, stock-market

FRED posts the Buffet Ratio here:

https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/DDDM01USA156NWDB

But it ends in 2017, anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indicator is taken from the World Bank's [Global Financial Development dataset](https://datacatalog.worldbank.org/dataset/global-financial-development), which was "last updated in September 2019 and contains data through 2017".

Comment: Know where I can find more recent information on GDP and stock market cap?